# Force 16.04 to use APU

Tags: amd-processor

I have both APU and GPU.
I would like UI to use A8-6500 with Radeon, so GTX can be used by tensorflow.
Is it possible to force UI to use APU?

```
$ nvidia-smi
Sun Jun 10 10:47:07 2018       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 384.81                 Driver Version: 384.81                    |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 980 Ti  Off  | 00000000:01:00.0  On |                  N/A |
|  0%   52C    P0    76W / 275W |     92MiB /  6070MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0      2417      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                            90MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: It uses APU by default.

Comment: Is it a desktop? Where is your monitor plugged in?